# ACL not working in ubuntu 16.04, ext3?

Tags: server, permissions, acl

I'm new to ACL's in linux (but aware of them from windows), and am trying to set up write access (for mr_green) to a folder in a different user's home folder (mr_blue). What happens is that mr_green is consistently getting "Permission Denied" errors. I'm pretty sure I've set everything up properly, but I'm not positive if it's me or my filesystem's config....

Here's what getfacl returns:

```
mr_blue@vps_machine:~$ whoami
mr_blue

mr_blue@vps_machine:~$ umask
0022

mr_blue@vps_machine:~$ getfacl shared_dir
# file: shared_dir
# owner: mr_blue
# group: mr_blue
user::rwx
user:mr_green:rwx
group::r-x
group:mr_green:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:mr_green:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:mr_green:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

mr_blue@vps_machine:~$ ls -al .
...
drwxrwx---+  2 mr_blue mr_blue 4096 Dec 15 13:34 shared_dir
```

And the contents of that folder are:

```
mr_blue@vps_machine:~$ ls -al shared_dir
total 16
drwxrwx---+  2 mr_blue mr_blue 4096 Dec 15 13:34 .
drwxr-x---  21 mr_blue mr_blue 4096 Dec 15 11:58 ..
-rw-rwxr--+  1 mr_blue mr_blue    6 Dec 15 16:42 ok.txt


mr_blue@vps_machine:~$ getfacl shared_dir/ok.txt
# file: shared_dir/ok.txt
# owner: mr_blue
# group: mr_blue
user::rw-
user:mr_green:rwx
group::r-x
group:mr_green:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

And when I log in as mr_green, I get Permission Denied errors:

```
mr_green@vps_machine:~$ whoami
mr_green

mr_green@vps_machine:~$ umask
0022

mr_green@vps_machine:~$ cat /home/mr_blue/shared_dir/ok.txt
cat: /home/mr_blue/shared_dir/ok.txt: Permission denied
```

Looking around the web for various indicators of problems, it seems that it should be working ok... but I don't understand why it's not. Any help or suggestions welcome!

Here's the results of various config that may be related:

```
# mount | grep vda1
/dev/vda1 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,quota,usrquota,grpquota,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)

# mount -v -o remount,acl /dev/vda1
mount: /dev/vda1 mounted on /.

# mount | grep vda1
/dev/vda1 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,quota,usrquota,grpquota,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)

# tune2fs -l /dev/vda1 | grep "Default mount options"
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl

# cat /etc/fstab 
...
UUID=xxx       /       ext3    defaults,acl,errors=remount-ro,rw,grpquota,usrquota    0

# cat /boot/config-4.4.0-170-generic | grep ACL
CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_REISERFS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_JFS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_XFS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_F2FS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_TMPFS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_HFSPLUS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V2_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=m
CONFIG_CEPH_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_CIFS_ACL=y
CONFIG_9P_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
```

I notice that the last command doesn't list anything for `CONFIG_EXT3...` so it could be a cause...? But I don't know if this is so, nor how to proceed...

Comment: I am not very familiar with ACLs. I have used them once (with no problem), but my filesystem is EXT4. Can you try by creating a test EXT4 filesystem?

Comment: Does `mr_green` have read and browse access to `/home/mr_blue`?

Comment: @fkraiem No, `mr_green` has no particular access to `/home/mr_blue`. They both have underpreviledged access, in general. I thought that was the point with ACLs though... in order to give fine grained access to *only* the parts necessary? Do I need to give access all the way up the chain (to `/` even?) and what level `r/rw/rwx`?

Comment: Even with ACLs, a user can't access a subdirectory without first accessing the parent directory, so he must have at least `rx` access to all path components. If you don't want to give access to `/home/mr_blue`, you need to put the shared directory somewhere public like `/home/green_and_blue` and give access to both users. Then each user can make a symlink to it in their own home dir for easy access if they wish.

Comment: @fendonkadifeli, I tested on ext4 and the problem is the same.

Comment: @fkraiem. Can you add this as an answer so that I can mark it complete? many thanks! (disappointing, but thanks!). I was hoping to not have the folder as 'public' as you mention.

Comment: By "public" I meant not within any user's home directory, which the user may wish to keep entirely private. You can of course make the directory accessible only to those two users (and root), though other users will still see that the directory exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with ACLs, a user can only access a directory if they can access every path component, so here access to `/home/mr_blue/shared_dir` requires access to all of `/`, `/home`, `/homr/mr_blue`, and `/home/mr_blue/shared_dir`. Write access is not needed to parent directories of course, since the user does not need to write in them, only `r`ead and e`x`ecute (browse).

If `mr_blue` does not wish to give access to `/home/mr_blue`, the shared directory must be created elsewhere on the system, as a subdirectory of a directory that both users can access. Access to the directory can of course be restricted to those two users only (and root). The users can also create a symbolic link to it in their home directory for easy access, if they wish

Comment: adding a `setfacl -m u:mr_green:r-x` onto `\home\mr_blue` did the trick. Thanks